# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-state, flutter-build

I have noticed a new lint issue in my project.

Long story short:

**I need to use BuildContext in my custom classes**

flutter lint tool is not happy when this being used with aysnc method.

Example:

```
   MyCustomClass{

      final buildContext context;
      const MyCustomClass({required this.context});

      myAsyncMethod() async {
        await someFuture();
        # if (!mounted) return;          << has no effect even if i pass state to constructor
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); #   << example
      }
   }
```

Comment: doesn't seem wise to pass context to objects like that for the purpose of navigation. If your navigation stack changes after you have passed the context to MyCustomClass and you try to navigate again using the old context, you will get errors.

Comment: I agree, then how this scenario should be approached?

Comment: Use some state management like BloC, where you can trigger navigation when a state changes. So long as you do not store your context, but instead, use the context for navigation purposes without storing the instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69512692/1032613

Comment: There is no context.mounted property. Please update answer.

Comment: @Scorb It will be there in next flutter major update.

Comment: Try to switch the flutter channel to beta using 'flutter channel beta'. It looks like 'mounted' is an experimental param.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

**Update Flutter 3.7+** :

`mounted` property is now officially added to `BuildContext`, so you can check it from everywhere, whether it comes from a StatefulWidget State, or from a Stateless widget.

While storing context into external classes stays a bad practice, you can now check it safely after an async call like this :

```dart
class MyCustomClass {
  const MyCustomClass();

  Future<void> myAsyncMethod(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(/*waiting dialog */);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    if (context.mounted) Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}

// Into widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () => const MyCustomClass().myAsyncMethod(context),
      icon: const Icon(Icons.bug_report),
    );
  }
// Into widget
```

---

*Original answer*

Don't stock context directly into custom classes, and don't use context after async if you're not sure your widget is mounted.

Do something like this:

```dart
class MyCustomClass {
  const MyCustomClass();

  Future<void> myAsyncMethod(BuildContext context, VoidCallback onSuccess) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    onSuccess.call();
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () => const MyCustomClass().myAsyncMethod(context, () {
        if (!mounted) return;
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }),
      icon: const Icon(Icons.bug_report),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can you do it in a StatelessWidget?

Comment: @stk I don't think you can, a StatelessWidget don't really have a lifecycle (no state). But if you want an async method, then you have a long-ish thing to do, and you want the app user to see something is happening, so you need a state.
If you look at your app, you should see where you need to handle this state and create a Stateful widget.

Comment: @stk In stateless widget, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69512692/11675817

Comment: that genius xD , what i have been doing is making all the methods inside the widget class just so i can get access to the mounted lol , but this actually will help a lot , thank you sir

Comment: I think  the flow of the code dosen't changes anything using this method, even if we use the async method outside it just avoids that lints. but the issue remains the same.

Comment: @TarunNagaSai what issue do you see with this method ? The main issue (besides the justified lint warning) of the question was to call the navigator of a potentially unmounted context, after an async call. In this version, the navigator is called after the async method, but only if the component is mounted, removing the issue (and the lint warning).

Comment: @stk answer updated for stateless widgets on Flutter 3.7+

Comment: I get error `the getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'` . I am using stateless widget

Comment: @Aseem are you using Flutter 3.7 ?

Comment: "While storing context into external classes stays a bad practice". So you can't pass the build context to extracted functions? What would be an alternative for keeping the code clean?

Comment: @Marcel you can pass it, but not keep it as an internal property of an external class. context is only a part of the current displayed UI, and can evolve (and be unmounted) on each new frame, that's why it's all good when used synchronously, but you must check its mounted state after asynchronous process (because process is running while UI is evolving).

Comment: @Guildem I'm having an asynchronous function inside my provider class. So I must wait it completes before navigating to another route. It looks like:
if( context.mounted ) {  
        await  context.read<MyProvider>().myFunc();
        Navigator.of(context)..movingRoute; // issue still warning at this line
 }
To fix this I have to put two these lines into 2 if statements. Which looking so dumb.

Is there another solution for this, sir?

Comment: @HuỳnhĐứcBùi You need to test if your context is mounted AFTER each async call, so after your myFunc() call. The purpose is to check if something happened in your widgets tree while async call was running, before trying anything else with your context.

Answer (score 102):

#### Use `context.mounted`*

In `StatefulWidget`/`StatelessWidget` or in any class that has `BuildContext`:

```dart
void foo(BuildContext context) async {
  await someFuture();
  if (!context.mounted) return;
  Navigator.pop(context); // No warnings now
}
```

<sub>* If you're in a `StatefulWidget`, you can also use just `mounted` instead of `context.mounted`</sub>

Comment: Can you please explain the `StatelessWidget` example? Where do we pass in `mounted` of `false`?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins `StatelessWidget` is always mounted, so you never have to pass `mounted: false` in them, but to get away with the warning, it's better to have a field named `mounted` set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting. Is that in any docs? I don't feel like it is well known.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins This entire solution/concept is nowhere in the docs (as far as I know). Docs may suggest you to convert your `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and then use `mounted` flag to check if the widget is in the tree.

Comment: Ah, I see `mounted` is on `BuildContext` now. And it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Isn't the `StatelessWidget` example effectively just masking the warning? The root issue--using the context across an async gap--is still there (due to `await`).

Comment: `the getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'` I get this error on my stateless widget

Comment: @Aseem Update your Flutter version using `flutter upgrade`.

Answer (score 40):

If your class can extend from `StatefulWidget` then adding

```
if (!mounted) return;
```

would work!

**EDIT**

I had this issue again and again and here's the trick - use or declare variables using `context` before using async methods like so:

```
    MyCustomClass{
      const MyCustomClass({ required this.context });

      final buildContext context;
      
      myAsyncMethod() async {
        // Declare navigator instance (or other context using methods/classes)
        // before async method is called to use it later in code
        final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
       
        await someFuture();
        
        // Now use the navigator without the warning
        navigator.pop();
      }
    }
```

**EDIT END**

As per Guildem's answer, he still uses

```
if (!mounted) return;
```

so what's the point of adding more spaghetti code with callbacks? What if this `async` method will have to pass some data to the methods you're also passing `context`? Then my friend, you will have even more spaghetti on the table and another extra issue.

The core concept is to not use `context` after async bloc is triggered ;)

Comment: This solution does not work. It has exactly the same problem as if you had called ```Navigator.of(context).pop()``` directly from the async method. If this hides the related analyzer warning, it is only a bug in the analyzer.

Comment: what about if I don't have a stateful widget and I have that navigator code inside a normal class?

Comment: Hey guys, please see my answer after edit. I have found the solution for this problem after many tries myself as this issue was sometimes visiting me back and I said enough :)

Comment: As it is, your answer is wrong. Context can't be used without checking mounted before use on async method. On the custom class, without StatefulWidget implementation, you must let the caller of myAsyncMethod check a context it may not have itself here (because you gave context at the wrong step and it may have changed since constructor).

There's no spaghetti code in the accepted answer. Only adaptation for the "Flutter isn't happy when I use context in my custom async method of my custom class". And there's no reason a service class do UI stuff itself. Not its role.

Comment: As a confirmation of my solution, you can even see the comments under your own answer, which states similarly, here you have also richer explanation why this solution is correct and is not used in any case only to silence the warning: stackoverflow.com/a/69512692/11675817. Your answer is not being denied, your answer is correct. Sometimes there are more complex functions which requires handling additional parameters on return and that makes it problematic - more code, and then resulting in spaghetti code. Using context before async gap is solution, also with connection with things like BLOC.

Comment: This is not every inituitive, but adding that check fixed my problem. Gotta look further into this to figure out what exactly is the problem here... 

Comment: Minor correction: "final buildContext context;" should be: "final BuildContext context;" I could not edit the answer to fix this, so I'm commenting here...

Answer (score 9):

you can use this approach

```
myAsyncMethod() async {
    await someFuture().then((_){
    if (!mounted) return;          
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
  }
});
```

Now in you can access mounted from context anywhere in the widget and in any class that is using BuildContext like this

```dart
if(context.mounted){
// do your nvigation 
}else{
return;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use mounted check in a stateless widget its possible by making an extension on BuildContext

```
extension ContextExtensions on BuildContext {
  bool get mounted {
    try {
      widget;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and then you can use it like this

```
if (context.mounted)
```

Inspiration taken from [GitHub PR for this feature](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619) and it passes the same tests in the merged PR

Comment: I am looking for temporary solution for flutter version < 3.7. can i use this ?

Comment: Yes, i started using the solution with 3.3 i think, unsure if there are any issues with using it prior to that

Answer (score 9):

This help for me.

```
/// transition to the main page after a pause of 3 seconds
Future<void> _navigateToMainScreen(BuildContext context) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  if (context.mounted) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MainScreen()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In Flutter 3.7.0 `BuildContext` has the property `mounted`. It can be used both in StatelessWidget and StatefulWidgets like this:

```
void bar(BuildContext context) async {
  await yourFuture();
  if (!context.mounted) return;
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Comment: what if class is neither stateful not statless? e.g. any class with static methods and with no ui

Comment: @MuhammadUmairSaqib It is not about the widget. If you have a context, you can access the property `mounted` no matter if you are in a static class or not

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way I could found is

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {

    // your code which uses Buildcontext in async function

});
```

Comment: This solution (or variants of it) are already provided in existing, older answers. When answering older questions, please make sure you provide either a novel solution, or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. If an existing answer already has your preferred solution, consider upvoting that answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having this problem nowadays, a simple solution is to use a conditional with `context.mount`
**Example:**

```dart
 InkWell(
   onTap: () async {
             
     if (await controller.getOrderDetails(context,
          controller.orders.value[index].id!, index) 
          && >>> context.mounted <<<
            ) {
            await showModalBottomSheet(
             shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
               topLeft: Radius.circular(6.0), topRight:Radius.circular(6.0))),
             context: context,
             builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
               expand: false,
               minChildSize: .4,
               initialChildSize: .4,
               maxChildSize: .85,
               builder: (context, scrollController) => Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: [const DraggableIndicator(), widget],
              ),
            ),
          }
        }...
    ...
```

You will see that the warning in context will disappear

Comment: this way the context will stop showing the warning or misuse

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this in StatelessWidget you can refer to this example

```dart
class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Future<String>? onPressed;

  final bool mounted;

  const ButtonWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.mounted,
    this.onPressed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final errorMessage = await onPressed;
            if (errorMessage != null) {
              // This to fix: 'Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps'
              if (!mounted) return;
              snackBar(context, errorMessage);
            }
          },
          child: Text(title),
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

using buildcontext across async method or class is now not work in current version of flutter rather than introduce context in async await use method callback for navigation and other purposes

Answer (score -3):

Just simplify create a function to call the navigation

```
void onButtonTapped(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, which is about context in async calls. (also, formatting issues)

Answer (score -4):

just save your navigator or whatever needs a context to a variable at the beginning of the function

```
      myAsyncMethod() async {
        final navigator = Navigator.of(context); // 1
        await someFuture();
        navigator.pop();  // 2
      }
```

Comment: No be careful of doing that! context might not be mounted so absolutely this does not guarantee to fix the issue and might cause the app to crash instead!

Comment: @BermjlyTeam I do not understand how this might not fix the issue. The BuildContext was used to fetch the Navigator instance. The resulting instance is now fetched. After the await, we must not use the BuildContext. We don't. We only use the Navigator instance. How does this not fix the issue in at least a StatelessWidget ?

Comment: @Sxndrome imagine that your someFuture() waits 5 seconds (biiiiig task). During this time, you go back with Android back button or another implemented way. What //2 will do when someFuture() is finished ? Context before and after the future won't always be the same.

Comment: This is very close to being the correct answer. It just needs a check before calling navigator.pop().  Change to
`if (navigator.mounted) navigator.pop();`
I would also store the *NavigatorState* instead of *BuildContext*:
`MyCustomClass {
 final NavigatorState navigator;
 const MyCustomClass(this.navigator);
}`
Example instantiation:
`final obj = MyCustomClass(Navigator.of(context));`

Answer (score -11):

DO NOT use BuildContext across asynchronous gaps.

Storing BuildContext for later usage can easily lead to difficult to diagnose crashes. Asynchronous gaps are implicitly storing BuildContext and are some of the easiest to overlook when writing code.

When a BuildContext is used from a StatefulWidget, the mounted property must be checked after an asynchronous gap.

So, I think, you can use like this:

GOOD:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ...

  void onButtonTapped() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    if (!mounted) return;
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

BAD:

```
void onButtonTapped(BuildContext context) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Comment: You can't just copy and paste directly from documentation and not at least cite your source: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html