# Flutter Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct)

Tags: flutter

I've already checked the previous answer but can't help me.

I'm checking that user has internet or not if not then I'm showing pic of no internet. Now I've a button of `Retry` where user can click on it to check if he has internet back.

Now here I'm facing error when i click on `Retry` button

> Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
> E/flutter (25542): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.

My **Updated** splash screen

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString("token");
    print("Token obtained: $token");
    return token != null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _init();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    bool isConnected = await NetworkHelper.checkInternet();
    if (!isConnected) {
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CheckConnection(
                    onRetry: _init,
                  )),
        );
      }
    } else {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
        final isTokenValid = await isLoggedIn();
        if (isTokenValid) {
          if (mounted) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomNav()),
            );
          }
        } else {
          if (mounted) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Signup()),
            );
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: FlutterLogo(size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my image showing if there is no internet.

```
class CheckConnection extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onRetry;
  const CheckConnection({Key? key, required this.onRetry}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset("assets/image/no_internet.jpg"),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: onRetry,
            child: const Text("Retry"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems in your code. You are trying to access the `context` after what's called `asynchronous suspension`, i.e., you are accessing the `context` after some `Future` has done its work, while at that instance, the `context` might be in an invalid state, maybe because the `Element` tree has changed during this "asyncronois suspension". I also assume you are getting a warning about this but you are ignoring it.

The solution to this problem is, as the error suggests, use the getter `mounted` which is available inside the `State` class, after your `Future` does its work and before you access the `context`:

```
await Future.delayed(...);
if(mounted){
   // you can use the context
}
else{
   // you can't use the context
}
```

In your case, you need to check if the context is still valid by checking `mounted` variable before using it after a Future returns:

```
if(mounted) // you should put this check in all places where you use context after an asyncronous suspension
{
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomNav()),
          );
}
else{
// the context is not valid
// you should handle this case according to your app needs
}
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466478/waiting-asynchronously-for-navigator-push-linter-warning-appears-use-build).

Comment: Kindly can you edit the answer, how can i write it. as i'm new in flutter

Comment: i did like this but still same error

Comment: @ForStack can you please update your question with what you have tried?

Comment: I've updated my code for splash sacreen

Comment: @ForStack I meant update what you tried after I posted the answer, how are you checking if the context is mounted now?

Comment: I'm using like this everywhere  `if (mounted) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomNav()),
            );
          }`

Comment: @ForStack are you sure you are using it everywhere? From your updated question it looks you are doing the check only in the `if` block, and not in the `else` block.

Comment: check I've updated my splash screen according to your code

Comment: after using like this I'm getting token null when i clik on `retry` button.

Comment: I've one question, if I see this kind of warning `DON'T use BuildContext across asynchronous gaps.` should I've to use `if(mounted){...}`?

Comment: @ForStack in general, yes, it is dangerous to use the context without checking after an async gap, please check the linked answer above for more details