# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps. After update pub yaml to the major version

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have upgraded the pub yaml to the major version `flutter pub upgrade --major versions` and it gave me a lot of suggestions error I don’t understand why?. Can someone explain?

And this is for an example. It says `Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps` What am I suppose to do here.

```
_resetEmail(String password,) async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final credential =
        EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: user!.email!, password: password);
    try {
      UserCredential;
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
          ?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);

       ///The problem is here
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageTransition(
              type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
              child: const ResetEmailScreen()));
        ///

    } on FirebaseAuthException {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Wrong password',
        gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        textColor: Colors.black,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: lots of dupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369932/flutter-do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before Navigator.push add a condition `if (mounted)`. You are using a context in an async method. While this method is being executed the context can change. But this context is being passed to the navigator. Hence the error i think..

Comment: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'

Comment: @Aseem use "if (context.mounted)" instead

Answer (score 9):

Storing BuildContext in a method is causing Asynchronous gaps which can later cause difficulty in finding the problem if the app crashes.

Therefore, When a BuildContext is used from a StatefulWidget, the mounted property must be checked after an asynchronous gap.

**Solution**

Use "if (!mounted) return;" before using context.

```
if (!mounted) return;
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
          child: const ResetEmailScreen()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Best solution found to avoid "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps":

For a StateLess Widget :

```dart
if (context.mounted) {
   Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

For a StateFull Widget:

```dart
if (mounted) {
   Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
if(context.mounted)
    Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageTransition(
              type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
              child: const ResetEmailScreen()
          )
    );
```

Comment: please format your code and leave a small explanation

Comment: Markdown is supported on Stackoverflow, therefore you can use tripple backticks as the starting and ending symbol for code blocks. I fixed it for you. As cerdoc says, please explain why adding `if (context.mounted)` solves the question.