# Flutter Get Navigator context for async task

Tags: flutter

When I press the login button, I receive a Future. If true, then I change page, else I display a popup dialog.

```
onPressed: () async {
  final navigator = Navigator.of(context); // store the Navigator to enable .push

  bool? res = await sendUser('6@gmail.com', 'password');
  // if connection succeeds
  if (res) {
     navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const newScreen()));
  } else {
     showPopUp(context);
  }
}
```

I have the warning '**Do not use BuildContexts accros async gaps**' for the popup. I had this warning for Navigator.push, so I fixed it by storing the Navigator but I don't know what to do for the popup. Can I get like the context of navigator ?

Comment: Hey, here is solution of your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253529/7557223

Comment: I have a stateless widget, can't use 'mounted'

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding your `showPopUp` function inside an `if (mounted)` like so:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final navigator = Navigator.of(context); // store the Navigator to enable .push

  bool? res = await sendUser('6@gmail.com', 'password');
  // if connection succeeds
  if (res) {
     navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const newScreen()));
  } else if (mounted) { //Changed here <-------------
     showPopUp(context);
  }
}
```

PS: Caution when using ternary operators while [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/3465) is open

Comment: if (mounted) is used for stateful widget, I have stateless :/

Comment: I don't believe there is another way other than just ignoring the linter then. Changing your stateless widget to stateful is easy though, the Flutter extension gives a quick fix for that.