# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I've made a function for registration and I'm getting a warning `Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps.` on `Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("No Internet", context);` I'm new to flutter and want to know how to use `async` and `await`.

```
Future _registration() async {
    String name = _nameController.text.trim();
    String email = _emailController.text.trim();
    String password = _passwordController.text.trim();
    String phone = _phoneController.text.trim();

    if (name.isEmpty) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your name", context);
    } else if (email.isEmpty) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your email", context);
    } else if (!GetUtils.isEmail(email)) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type valid email address", context);
    } else if (password.isEmpty) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your password", context);
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
          "password can't be less than 6 characters", context);
    } else if (phone.isEmpty) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your phone", context);
    }
    else {
      var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
          connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        ApiCall.signUp(name, email, password, phone).then((value) {
          if (value.statusCode == 200) {
            if (json.decode(value.body)['success'] != null) {
              if (json.decode(value.body)["success"]) {
                RegisterResponse registerResponseModel =
                    RegisterResponse.fromJson(json.decode(value.body));
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, VerifyUser.routeName);
                Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                    'User Registered Successfully', context);
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print('User Registered Successfully');
                }
              } else {
                Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                    json.decode(value.body)["en_message"], context);
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print(json.decode(value.body).toString());
                }
              }
            }
          } else {
            Utils.flushBarErrorMessage('invalid data', context);
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(json.decode(value.body).toString());
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("No Internet", context);
      }
    }
  }
```

calling this `_registration()`

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _registration();
            },
            child: const Text('SignUp')),
```

Here is my `flushBarErrorMessage`.

```
   class Utils {
  static void flushBarErrorMessage(String message, BuildContext context) {
    showFlushbar(
        context: context,
        flushbar: Flushbar(
          forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.decelerate,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          titleColor: Colors.white,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.error,
            size: 28,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
          positionOffset: 20,
          message: message,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        )..show(context));
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, this can help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72893730/edit) and include the function `Utils.flushBarErrorMessage`?

Comment: Hmm... would you please share the `showFlushbar` as well?

Comment: `showFlushbar` is from `another_flushbar` package.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Now I can test it

Comment: Have you read this https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html?

Comment: @lepsch have you found the solution?

Comment: Yes... posting an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that after an `await`, every use of the `BuildContext` will show this warning. This warning happens because using a `BuildContext` after an `await` could happen after the widget is disposed of. This way, the context wouldn't exist anymore and the app could even crash because of this. Check out [the official lint documentation](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html):

> Storing BuildContext for later usage can easily lead to difficult-to-diagnose crashes. Asynchronous gaps are implicitly storing BuildContext and are some of the easiest to overlook when writing code.

The easy solution, from the official docs, is the need to check for [`State.mounted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html). The code would look something like this on every place the warning shows up:

```dart
      ...
      } else {
        if (mounted) Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("No Internet", context);
      }
      ...
```

Comment: Hi bro, hope you are doing good. I've updated my question kindly check it. Thanks

Comment: Hi there. You actually should create another question instead of changing the existing one completely. This way the answers don’t match anymore  what you’re asking for. If possible revert it. Anyway, instead of passing the context to `doSignUp` return the result as an enum for example and resolve it on the caller side.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to the previous one to keep it in sync with the answers. If you have another question please create a new one and let me know.

Comment: My widget does not have a mounted variable.

Comment: @Scorb change it to statefull widget

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
///Add context
Future _registration(BuildContext context) async {
...
if(!mounted) return;
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, VerifyUser.routeName);
...
}
```

When calling:

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
             //make sure your class is of StatefulWidget()
              _registration(context); ///Add context
            },
            child: const Text('SignUp')),
```

Comment: same issue. As this is not a proper solution.

Comment: still same issue

Comment: this is proper solution

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward answer to this warning is:

Keep a copy of the **`context`** based component in a variable, to use after the **`await`** statement. Also, use the **`mounted`** check after the awaiting statement

---

For **`StatelessWidget`**

keep referencing the `context` usage before the `await` keyword.

example:

```
// navigation
onPressed: () async {
    final router = GoRouter.of(context);

    final result = await [
        Permission.location,
        Permission.locationAlways,
        Permission.locationWhenInUse
    ].request();

    if (...) {
        router.go(AppRouter.dashboard);
    } else {
        router.go(AppRouter.askForCustomLocation);
    }

// cubit
onPressed: () async {

    final appSettingsCubit = BlocProvider.of<AppSettingsCubit>(context);

    final result = await [
        Permission.location,
        Permission.locationAlways,
        Permission.locationWhenInUse
    ].request();

    if (...) {
        appSettingsCubit.locationProptAsked();
    } else {
        appSettingsCubit.locationProptAsked();
    }
```

---

For **`StatefullWidget`**

just wrap the `context` usage with a `if(mounted)` logic

example:

```
// navigation
onPressed: () async {    
    final result = await [
        Permission.location,
        Permission.locationAlways,
        Permission.locationWhenInUse
    ].request();

    if (...) {
        if(mounted) {
            router.go(AppRouter.dashboard);
        }
    } else {
        if(mounted) {
            router.go(AppRouter.dashboard);
        }
    }

// cubit
onPressed: () async {
    final result = await [
        Permission.location,
        Permission.locationAlways,
        Permission.locationWhenInUse
    ].request();

    if (...) {
        if(mounted) {
            BlocProvider.of<AppSettingsCubit>(context).locationProptAsked();
        }
    } else {
        if(mounted) {
            BlocProvider.of<AppSettingsCubit>(context).locationProptAsked();
        }
    }
```

---

That's all from my experience.