# How to call snackbar inside async method?

Tags: flutter

Here when you call snackbar inside async generally you may notice the warning or error saying that Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps. how to avoid this kind of situation in a class object, not in a widget tree

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps)

Comment: no you can see there he is using mounted inside widget I am talking only  about class and a function imagine if you want call snackbar according to response in api call then I think we can try below answer

Answer (score 6):

Wrap snackBar code inside a `context.mounted` if condition

```dart
if (context.mounted) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first I had created a showSnack bar method after that I used future.delay in async to call snackbar I hope this solution will help some one in future those who face this kind of situation following is my function for showSnack bar

```
void showsnackbar(BuildContext context, String text) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(text),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

following is my async function where I am calling showsnackbar function eg..if you want to show snackbar upon status code then you can do following method

```
class sample{
    Future<void> sample(BuildContext context) async {
    
    switch (res.statusCode) {
            case 201:
              Future.delayed(Duration.zero)
                  .then((value) => showsnackbar(context, "sample text"));
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add await with Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) => showsnaackbar(context,"Vehicle type inserted"));

Comment: ya we can use either way also