# Is there a way to avoid checking isMounted in Flutter when using async?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

If I am not using getx, is there a way to not check `isMounted` in Flutter when using async function? Refer to [Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps), it looks like we need to check `context.mounted` every time after async.

React says this is an anti-pattern https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html.

I am curious if there is a better way to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check isMounted if you await several (>1) async methods that has been called after each other (hence the "across async gaps" phrase).

If you extract the logic, that requires the awaiting, from the UI, then you often can avoid checking isMounted in the Widgets, and instead react appropriately on different types of events.