# flutter/dart: Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps in provider model class

Tags: flutter, dart

In the `provider` model I use context after `await` It shows warning `Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps` and I am unable to check with mounted because I use it in `Provider` class. so what I should do to remove this warning? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```dart
class SoloStartSiteScanningProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  FocusNode boxFocusNode = FocusNode();
  FocusNode locationFocusNode = FocusNode();
  Future checkBoxSealMatching(BuildContext context) async {
    try {    
      var barcode = await _scanBoxBarcode();
      if (barcode != "-1") {
        if (boxFieldController.text == barcode) {
          // Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(locationFocusNode);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(" coll lactaion scanning Exception=== $e");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```dart
Future checkBoxSealMatching(BuildContext context) async {
final focusScope = FocusScope.of(context);
FocusNode boxFocusNode = FocusNode();
...
        if (boxFieldController.text == barcode) {
          focusScope.requestFocus(locationFocusNode);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer  and this is also the right answer for many other situations

Comment: what we can do In this scenario if you have any idea plz  :                                                                                     Future checkBoxSealMatching(BuildContext context) async {
final focusScope = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (boxFieldController.text == barcode) {
        getTeam(context);       // Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps
        }
}

Comment: Get it right at the beginning something like this `final teamFuture = getTeam(context);`. When necessary, just wait for the future `final team = await teamFuture;`