# Build context cannot be used across async gap

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

if i directly call the navigator.pushnamed method I receive a message that says, Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps. I don't know how to solve this problem and move to next screen.
this is the code

````
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                title: 'Register',
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);
                    if (newUser.user != null) {
                      await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ChatScreen.id);
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
              ),
    ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing asynchronous tasks during widget's synchronous operations, you must check the widget is still available.

For your case, right before the `Navigator` line, add this line

```
if (!mounted) return;
```

By doing so you check the current `Widget` is **mounted and usable**. If the `Widget` is being rebuilt or destroyed, checking if it's mounted will return `false`.

If it returns `true` it means the `Widget` is ready and you can use async / sync tasks almost everywhere.

If this doesn't help or doesn't suit your case, please let me know and I'll provide more support, happy coding!