# How do I properly code this so that I don't get a warning about using BuildContext across an async gap?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was getting a warning that said

> Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps. (Documentation)  Try rewriting the code to not reference the 'BuildContext'.

I clicked on the Documentation link and did what they recommended, which was to add the line `if (!context.mounted) return;` (see below). However, I'm still getting the same warning although now it's pointing to the line I just added. What does this mean and what can I do to code this properly so that the warning doesn't appear? All I need this button to do is to run some asynchronous work and if it was successful then navigate to a different page.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final groupID = await database.createGroup();
      if (!context.mounted) return; //Warning points here
      if (groupID == '') {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error creating group');
      } else {
        groupNameController.clear();
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); //Close the dialog box
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenChat(groupID: groupID,)),
        );
      }
  },
  child: const Text('OK')
),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
if (!context.mounted) return;
```

Try using:

```
if (!mounted) return;
```

It will also suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
if (!context.mounted) return;
```

Try using:

```
if (context.mounted) {
} else {
  return;
}
```

It will suppress the warning.

Comment: That does seem to suppress it, but is that the correct way to go about this? Shouldn't I be refactoring this button so that the warning never appears in the first place?

Comment: I added a new answer. Check it out.

Comment: Yes I see the other answer, but my question is if it is good practice to suppress warnings or if I should be changing my code to not make the warning appear

Comment: Yes, it's good practice. See my lint file here: https://gist.github.com/dharambudh1/8e729f5b003f33dac32b1fb40df636bc

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the user could close the app or go to another page/screen of your app while the async function is still loading/progressing, which would cause an error after its complete because it can't execute the next line `(if/else)` or check `(!context)`.

For this reason you need to check if this page/screen is still `mounted`, and if so you're asking it to continue executing the next lines, or dismiss it. Simply call it this way:

```
onPressed: () async {
    final groupID = await database.createGroup();
      if (mounted){}
      if (groupID == '') {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error creating group');
      } else {
        groupNameController.clear();
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); //Close the dialog box
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenChat(groupID: groupID,)),
        );
      }
  },
```