# how to context.read in flutter when I can't use context across sync gaps?

Tags: flutter, dart

as title I have a final globalState = context.read();

I get the error

Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
Try rewriting the code to not reference the 'BuildContext'.

why should I use the context.mounted in this case?! this seem like an ugly solution

Example code:

```
class Example extends State<Example> {
  Future<Params> _onCompleted(String example) async {
    try {
final globalState = context.read<GlobalState>();
    } catch (exception, stackTrace) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if (context.mounted) {} method doesn't work: what error it shows?

Comment: Could you add some code to help us understand better?

Comment: Shared it in the post. The problem is that "globalState" has to be also accessed inside of the catch..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps)