# How to solve "Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps" in BLoC

Tags: flutter

I am using routing and snack bar in the BLoC file which is not stateless or stateful.

```
  if (event is AuthenticationLogout) {
  emit(AuthenticationLoading());
  try {
    user = await _repository.getUserDetails();
    final response = await _repository.logout(user!.token);
    if (response == 1) {
      emit(AuthenticationNotAuthenticated());
         Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(event.context,
          RouteConstants.rcLogin, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(event.context)
        ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(event.context)
      ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red));
  }
}
```

I am passing context in event which I use in my logic. But I am getting this warning:

```
Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
Try rewriting the code to not reference the 'BuildContext'.
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps). But it doesn't fit in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your flutter / dart Version ?

Comment: Try this before using any api/func/method with context if(context.mounted){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with that the linked answer doesn't fit. You should be able to check for `mounted` just fine, so like

```
  if (event is AuthenticationLogout) {
  emit(AuthenticationLoading());
  try {
    user = await _repository.getUserDetails();
    final response = await _repository.logout(user!.token);
    if (response == 1) {
      emit(AuthenticationNotAuthenticated());
      if (event.context.mounted) {
           Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(event.context,
            RouteConstants.rcLogin, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    } else {
      if (event.context.mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(event.context)
          ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
          ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red));
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (event.context.mounted){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(event.context)
        ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red));
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Hmm.. strange. Might be simply because the context is behind another variable (event). Maybe writing it like this might work.

```
  if (event is AuthenticationLogout) {
  emit(AuthenticationLoading());
  final context = event.context;
  try {
    user = await _repository.getUserDetails();
    final response = await _repository.logout(user!.token);
    if (response == 1) {
      emit(AuthenticationNotAuthenticated());
      if (context.mounted) {
           Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
            RouteConstants.rcLogin, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    } else {
      if (context.mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
          ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red));
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (context.mounted){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I applied if (event.context.mounted), but still getting a warning

Comment: @AizanSagheer try my edit

Comment: Still the same, because context is not defined. This is not part of a stateless or stateful widget, I also mentioned it in my question.

Comment: @AizanSagheer I know that, that's why the line `final context = event.context;` is there

Answer (score 1):

we use bloc state management for separation of logic. But in your case you have mixed the 2 i would firstly separate the 2 by putting the snackbar code in th page file rather than the bloc file for example

your authentication bloc file might look like this

```
if (event is AuthenticationLogout) {
  emit(AuthenticationLoading());
  try {
    user = await _repository.getUserDetails();
    final response = await _repository.logout(user!.token);
    if (response == 1) {
      emit(AuthenticationNotAuthenticated());
    } else {
      emit(AuthenticationError(message: LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()));
   
    }
  } catch (e) {
    emit(AuthenticationError(message: LocaleKeys.try_again_message.tr()));
  
  }
}
```

then your ui might look like this

```
BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            //Show a loading indicator
          } else if (state is AuthenticationNotAuthenticated){
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
          RouteConstants.rcLogin, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          } else if (state is AuthenticationError){
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(state.message),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red));
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return //display something
        },
      );
```

Comment: It's a beautiful approach. But I am working on an already written project which is too big to change. So I just want to remove this warning without changing the BLoC