# Navigate to another screen when api response success in flutter with provider

Tags: flutter, navigation, provider

After a while searching on stackoverflow, there is no answer that exactly what I need.
Example like: At the Login screen, after press 'login' button, I will call post api, then wait the response and check if it true will navigate to HomeScreen.
But the current way I am using now always get 'Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps'
So what is the right way to use with provider.

```
      void login({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String userName,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final loginResult = await DoLoginApi(DanhMucNguoiSuDungLoginRequest(
      Ma: userName,
      MatKhau: password,
    ));
    if (loginResult.Status == '0') {
      setCurrentUser(loginResult);
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen()));
    } else {
      loginMsg = loginResult.ErrorMsg;
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871880/do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps) this post might be helpful

Comment: already tried with context.mounted . but in another situation, like a make a post api on back button( I'm mean back to the previous screen by using popscope and do Post api) that if I use context.mounted, I will get stuck of it for may be 1 2seconds due to wait for the Post api finsh otherwise , if dont use it and A Dialog show up. but it back to the previous already, I will have problem due to the current screen is no longer in the widget tree